Create a mirror-like reflective material in Reality Composer Pro
I want to create a mirror like effect which reflects just virtual meshes, not real life scenes.
The only material that reflects the environment is "Metal" but unfortunately it's not enough. The text on the virtual mesh should be properly readable and clear. With the metal material it's too blurry.

Is this possible with the Shader Graph or do I need to have a look into the Metal Graphics Library from Apple?
I already tried all the materials provided by apple:
Apple Materials

Mirror-like Physically-Based Material
By default, the RealityKit render engine forces all your shaders with a reflection channel to reflect only the AR probe-based environment, neither self-reflection nor reflection of other VR models in the scene are not allowed. Unfortunately, there's no a convenient high-level "button" to turn it ON. Not 100% sure, but in order to turn RealityKit's Screen Space Reflections on (like in SceneKit), you might use low-level Compositor Services.
Nonetheless, to create a mirror-like PBR shader, you only need to set a metallic channel's value to 1, and roughness channel value to 0. The base color should be white. Here are a mirror and a red ball created programmatically.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    let mirror = ModelEntity(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 0.9, height: 1.4))
    let sphere = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.2))
    
    init() {
        mirror.position = [0.0, 1.0,-2.0]
        sphere.position = [0.0, 1.0,-1.5]
    }
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            var mirrorMaterial = PhysicallyBasedMaterial()
            mirrorMaterial.baseColor.tint = .white
            mirrorMaterial.metallic = 1.0
            mirrorMaterial.roughness = 0.0
            mirror.model?.materials = [mirrorMaterial]
            
            var ballMaterial = PhysicallyBasedMaterial()
            ballMaterial.baseColor.tint = .red
            sphere.model?.materials = [ballMaterial]
            
            rvc.add(mirror)
            rvc.add(sphere)
        }
    }
}


In Reality Composer Pro 2.0, a mirror material settings are as simple as that:


Thanks for your answer! Yes that's what I've already tried. The mirror itself does not reflect the VR models that are close to it, so it also doesn't reflect the red ball.
I've wondered if it's possible to create the desired effect wit the Shader Graph

This feature is contained not in the shader settings, but in the RealityKit's render engine settings. In SceneKit API, for example, it's called Screen-Space Reflection (SSR).
